# Bootstrap navbar behaviour on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, jekyll

I am building a Bootstrap 4 site using Jekyll. I have a jumbotron on each page which is working as a hero header. Everything works great until I resize to a mobile viewport. At this point the jumbotron gets tucked beneath the fixed header instead of occupying its own space beneath it. As shown in image.

When I unfix the header, the flow behaves normally. I have yet to make any style changes. So far all I am working with is Bootstrap HTMS and default stylings

How can I prevent this from happening whilst retaining a fixed header? I have posted both the body and nav HTML that I am using within Jekyll to build the pages.

Sincere thanks in advance for any pointers :)

```html
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <!--Site logo-->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Thomas Bishop</a>
    <!--Collapse nav on mobile viewports-->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
      <!--Nav links-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <!--Home-->
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <!--Services-->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <!--Expertise-->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/expertise">Expertise</a>
          </li>
          <!--Blog-->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/blog">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <!--About-->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/about">About</a>
          </li>
          <!--Contact-->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</nav>
</header>
```

```html
---
layout: default
title: Content Usage Policy
permalink: /content-usage-policy
---
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-light">
    <h1 class="display-4 d-flex justify-content-center">Content Usage Policy</h1>
    <p class="lead d-flex justify-content-center">Optional sub-heading or meta description</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>



</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As you are using class `jumbotron` it's providing `padding-top: 4rem` in large devices and `padding-top: 2rem` in small devices that's why your content overlap with the header in the small devices.

FYI as `position: fixed` is applied on the nav, for the other elements on the page nav does not exist so your next div will also start from `top: 0`. Inspect the element and view `<div class="container-fluid">` you can see it also started from `top:0`. To fix this issue do the following:

```
body > .container-fluid {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

By applying this css, gap between nav and content will increase and if you don't want this extra gap than instead of applying above css rule just apply this for small devices.

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    body > .container-fluid {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
}
```

And place this css such that it will load after the bootstrap's main css.

Comment: Thank you Aditi for clarifying the reasons for the problem and for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply apply a `margin-top` or `padding-top` **equivalent to your fixed header height** to your jumbotron using a mobile media query. [Here](https://codepen.io/parkerbennett/pen/hbzJm) is a link to a pen detailing a fixed header behavior.

Comment: Thank you Jake this makes sense .